# How to implement inheritance in a mongoose database for good coding practices?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, mongoose, database-design, architecture

I have 2 different types of payments, one should receive a booking and the other one a subscription. "Booking payment is accepted once the user accepts the booking", however, the "Subscription payment" has to be charged immediately after the validation is successful. However when I tried to display my pending payments inside my ANGULAR app I realized that now I have inside the same "Payment table" 2 different types of payments, some are invalid as the first schema is receiving a booking and on other payments, I have a subscription.

I created 2 different schemas but they are way too similar, I want to have good coding practices so I want to create an inheritance architecture inside my mongoose Schemas. I tried also to use `Schema.Types.Mixed` but I don't like that approach as I think is unsafe.

**PAYMENT SCHEMA**

```
const rentalPaymentSchema = new Schema({
    fromUser: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    toUser: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    ...
    booking: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Booking'},
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('RentalPayment', rentalPaymentSchema );
```

**SUBSCRIPTION SCHEMA**

```
const subscriptionPaymentSchema = new Schema({
    fromUser: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    toUser: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    ...
    susbscription: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subscription'},
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('SubscriptionPayment', subscriptionPaymentSchema );
```

How can I merge both schemas into one who has all common attributes on it and then creates 2 more schemas which inherit from the parent one?
Thanks in advance